# Is it ok to supply power over recommended, but under maximum rating?

Tags: power-supply, flipflop

I have a PCB application, which utilizes a very small and tightly packed PCB, featuring a D-flip flop with a Schmitt-triggered inverted output, specifically the [SN74AUP1G80](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74aup1g80.pdf) from TI.

The datasheet states that the *Absolute Maximum Voltage* is 4.6V, while the *Recommended Maximum Operating Voltage* is 3.6V. However, I am using a LiPo battery that reaches a maximum voltage of 4.2V when fully charged, and I need to power the flip flop.

My concern is whether it's acceptable to power the flip flop directly with the battery voltage, given that I don't have any space available for a regulator.

Comment: The LVC family has a higher voltage range (~1.6 to 5.5V), e.g. SN74LVC1G80

Comment: Confusingly the datasheet has a bug in the _Typical Application_ section, showing a VCC from 1.65 to 5.5 V.

Comment: @Mat Unfortunaly, I couldn't find any in the LVC series that has inverted output and schmitt trigger.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The SN74AUP1G80 [datasheet](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/sn74aup1g80.pdf) contains the following note in the *6.1 Absolute Maximum Ratings* section:

> (1) Stresses beyond those listed under *Absolute Maximum Ratings* may cause permanent damage to the device. These are stress ratings only, which do not imply functional operation of the device at these or any other conditions beyond those indicated under *Recommended Operating Conditions*. Exposure to absolute-maximum-rated conditions for extended periods may affect device reliability.

In other words, operating the power supply voltage above the Maximum specified in the *Recommended Operating Conditions*, but below the *Absolute Maximum Ratings*, means the manufacturer doesn't guarantee correct functional operation of the device.

E.g. it might work in a single development board, but lead to intermittent issues in a large production run.

Answer (score 6):

If you operate a component above the absolute maximum voltage specified in a datasheet, then you should not be surprised if the component is **damaged**. If you operate a component above the maximum recommended operating voltage, it shouldn't be damaged, but you should not be surprised if the component **does not work according to specification**, i.e. it may make errors etc.

It may if fact work properly, but it may not. That is what the maximum recommended operating voltage specification in the datasheet is telling you.